# Understanding Python Class Initialization

Tags: python, superclass

Suppose I have two classes:

```
class A():
    pass

class B():
    pass
```

I have another class

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, cond):
        if cond ==True:
           # class C initialize with class A
        else:
           # class C initialize with class B
```

If I inherit from A or B, by this implementation is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The way you have written your code, class `C` has no relationship to either `A` or `B`.

Comment: You've also forgotten two underscores; it should be `__init__`.

Comment: that is i want to write one class as wrapper of two other class... and want to access object of these two class by a single class .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the class use the `__class__` variable.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, cond):
        if cond ==True:
           self.__class__ = A
        else:
           self.__class__ = B
        self.__class__.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Ugh! No! Gross! Don't do this!

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't give a very good example why that could ever be useful I'll just assume that you didn't understand OOP.

What you're trying to do might be some kind of factory pattern:

```
def something_useful(cond):
    if cond:
        return A()
    else:
        return B()

myobj = something_useful(cond)
```

or maybe you want aggregation:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, something_useful):
        # store something_useful because you want to use it later
        self.something = something_useful

# let C use either A or B - then A and B really should inherit from a common base
if cond:
    myobj = C(A())
else:
    myobj = C(B())
```

Comment: Yes, you can just rename `something_useful` to `C` and it's a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to do some sort of mix-in depending on the value of cond?

If so try

```
class C(object):
    def __init(self, cond):
        if cond ==True:
           self.__bases__ += A
        else:
           self.__bases__ += B
```

I'm not 100% sure this is possible since perhaps it only works C.**bases** += A.  If it's not possible then what you are trying to do is probably not possible.  C should either inherit from A or from B.

Comment: AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__bases__'  is nor working

Answer (score 1):

While I'll not be as severe as Jochen, I will say that you are likely taking the wrong approach. Even if it is possible, you're far better off using [multiple inheritance](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) and having an AC and a BC class.

Eg:

```
class A():
    pass

class B():
    pass

class C():
    #do something unique which makes this a C
    pass

#I believe that this works as is?
class AC(A,C):
    pass

class BC(B,C):
    pass
```

This way, you can simply call

```
def get_a_c(cond):
    if cond == True:
       return AC()
    return BC()
```